# React-native-image-picker issue with video on android 13, launch camera returns {"didCancel": true}

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker, android-13

When the launchCamera function is called in the app to record a video, launchCamera function returns `{"didCancel": true}`.

```
const pickedFiles = await launchCamera({
          mediaType: 'video',
          quality: 0.8,
          cameraType: 'back',
        })
```

I am running the app on emulator device Android 13.

I tried with the version 4.8.5 of react-native-image-picker (the version in the project of my company) and the latest one 5.4.2 , had the same result with both versions.
i have not tried on physical device yet.
Works fine on android 12 and below

Anyone as a solution about this issue for android 13?

Comment: just tried on physical device and works fine

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution for the same issue:
[React Image Picker Issue Android 13](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1849)

Adding this line into android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml fixed mine.